# Wordpress language permalink

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I can't find a real solution here about how can i make custom language permalinks in Wordpress.

For translation i use loco translater plugin (basically it's a .po,.pot file editor)

I need this structure:

`domain.com/` - homepage orig language

`domain.com/en/` - homepage english

`domain.com/blog/` - blog post list from nl_NL category

`domain.com/en/blog/` - blog post list from en_US category

`domain.com/blog/this-is-a-post/` - blog post if it's in nl_NL category

`domain.com/blog/en/this-is-a-post/` - blog post  if it's in en_US category

.htaccess is not solution because the blog post custom permalinks

The best solution would be something like:

*If there is /en/ right after the url, wordpress read permalinks after /en/, not after the url, and send a get parameter "lang=en_US"*

*If there isn't /en/ everything is normal.*

Thank you for your help!

Peter

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for some plugin to provide this functionality but you are looking for a very custom permalink pattern. Outside of modifying server-side, I don't see how else to do it. Why is a custom `.htaccess` file out of the question? You can easily make an `.htaccess` file that also handles the blog permalinks.

Comment: As i told, .htaccess is not a solution. Using post-name-permalink overwrites htaccess rules, i've tried. And i wouldn't like to use plugin, i would lie to solve it programatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I figure out the solution.

```
function filter_post_link($permalink, $post) {

    $cat_ID = get_the_category($post->ID)[0]->cat_ID;
    if ($post->post_type != 'post')
        return $permalink;
    if($cat_ID==3){
    return 'en'.$permalink;
    }else{
        return $permalink;
    }
}
add_filter('pre_post_link', 'filter_post_link', 10, 2);

function my_add_rewrite_rules() {
    global $wp,$wp_rewrite;
    $wp->add_query_var('lang');
    add_rewrite_rule('^en/?$', 'index.php?lang=en_US', 'top');


    add_rewrite_rule('^blog/?$', 'index.php?cat=4', 'top');
    add_rewrite_rule('^blog/page/([0-9]+)/?$', 'index.php?cat=4&paged=$matches[1]', 'top');

    add_rewrite_rule('^en/blog/?$', 'index.php?lang=en_US&cat=3', 'top');
    add_rewrite_rule('^en/blog/page/([0-9]+)/?$', 'index.php?lang=en_US&cat=3&paged=$matches[1]', 'top');

    add_rewrite_rule('^en/?([^/]+)/?$', 'index.php?name=$matches[1]&lang=en_US', 'top');
    // Once you get working, remove this next line
  $wp_rewrite->flush_rules(false);  

}
add_action('init', 'my_add_rewrite_rules');
```

Explanation:
I can use `add_rewrite_rule()` function instead of .htaccess if i would like to use permalinks instead of plain urls.

The format of this function very similar to .htaccess, don't need more explanation.

The filter_post_link function forces `/en/`part to url before post slug, IF post category id = 3.

Everything works like a charm! :)

PS:
If you would like to get the values from your custom permalink, for example 'lang' parameter, you can do it this way:

```
$wp_query->query_vars['lang']
```

Comment: Very interesting approach, thanks for sharing. You ought to write this up in a blog post or something.